# html e-mail looks bad in yahoo and outlook but fine on everything else

Tags: html, css, email

Simply put: I have an html e-mail that was exported from psd. Sliced the layers and all that, changed the urls and all that, so i did a test mail and the html mail looks ok on most clients but when i send it to a yahoo mail or hotmail/outlook and open them from chrome, all the images are there but their places are wrong. What am i doing wrong? It's all in tables, no external css or no style in head.

```
<head></head>
```

Now with jsfiddle requirement out of the way

Here's the html https://jsfiddle.net/waev6gdu/

It appears fine on jsfiddle but not on the said clients. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: E-mail is drama...try to add `style="display:block"` to every img in the code.

Comment: Goddammit, and now it's broken for mac. https://jsfiddle.net/6oxwgn6q/ I was sooo happy to see it working in gmail browsers.

Comment: From the insane amount of rowspans and colspans in your code it looks like you exported this via some Photoshop or Brackets plugin. Forgive me if I'm wrong but if I'm not please don't ask people to fix it. There really aren't any shortcuts to HTML email development outside of pre-built templates.

Comment: Yeah i exported it via photoshop but i've also looked around for pre-built templates and couldn't find any that was a)free b)had a layout like mine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i would sugest you to use table for main layouth and divs inside td tags

so something like

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <!-- header -->
        <div style="width:50%;margin:50px;"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <!-- main content -->
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <!-- footer -->
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth having a look at this https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ it will show you what clients support certain css properties. Email development is a tricky, but tools like [Litmus](https://litmus.com/) can help with testing as well.

For images a structure like this may be helpful:

```
<tr>
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
              <img border="0" src="images/image.png" width="107" height="107">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<tr>
```

Using tables inside of tables and can help with email devlopment.

Comment: He is using exactly zero CSS in his template. While I agree that Campaign Monitor's guide is a good one, it has no bearing here at all.

Comment: The above example wouldn't work in emails for the simple reason that the image source is relative.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your issue, and I noticed several significant issues that are going to prevent this from working for you. You should take the time to read my comments, I am the author of CSS::Inliner for Perl, and I deal with issues like yours on a daily basis at my day job.

1. You are attempting to use an image based email. Emails of this nature are naturally filtered by a number of the mailbox providers out there. This technique was heavily abused by spammers for the obvious reason that you cannot analyze and examine the text content of an image easily. As a result it has become a giant red flag for the various filters out there. I *strongly* recommend that you avoid using this technique, as it will not only result in low engagement for this campaign, but can cause long term damage to your outbound reputation (i.e. more problems in the future).
2. You are relying on Adobe to autoformat your template for you. I'm sorry to say that the Adobe corporation knows zero about how to construct a proper HTML email. Their tools are entirely wrong to use for this task, continuing on with them will result in very poor rendering consistency. AFAIK there are no good automated tools for doing what you are trying to do, it must be done by hand, and it's extremely difficult.
3. You are relying on manual testing to determine if your email is rendering correctly. I cannot stress how useless this approach is. You simply cannot imagine how many different user agents there are out there in the wild. We are talking about 50, and that's just the major players - there are many other less players out there that you should also be concerned with (Android, I'm looking at you). I strongly suggest you look at Litmus or Email On Acid, both of which are reasonably priced, and do a relatively good job.
4. You are expecting this to be easy. It will not be. There is a reason that there are so many email companies out there, and it's because this is very hard detail-oriented work. There is no simple button that you can press that's going to handle this for you. If that's your preferred course of action you should hire a 3rd party to help you complete your email.

Comment: Other than the image side, this was helpful thank you. I've also tested it on litmus. That's why i'm here. :) It only looks bad on apple mail, outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013. Rest is smooth. As to why the image advice wasn't helpful? Well, because that big middle image right there? is here to stay :) I can only get rid of header and bottom images and make them html text. But that big fat image must stay.

Comment: Having images isn't a problem - but composing your entire email of images is a problem. You need to create a balance between text and images to get past the filters.

If you found my post helpful, please upvote.